# How to load module which is in different folder via Nestedmodules?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am having powershell module manifest file. Few of my psm1 file is in the same folder and one psm1 file is in one level above. I am trying to load it using 
NestedModules as below.

```
NestedModules = @('Tpn.psm1',
                  'Tpn_Alerts.psm1',
                  '..\IOOperation.psm1',
                  'TestCases.psm1')
```

In the list `IOOperation.psm1` is in one level above from current folder. So I added `..\` , but it fails as below:

> Test-ModuleManifest : The specified NestedModule entry '..\IOOperation.psm1' in the module manifest'C:\repo\Tpn\Tpn.psd1' is invalid.
>   Try again after updating this entry with valid values.

I tried using `$PsscriptRoot`, it also did not work. Is it possible to add a psm1 in different folder or not? If so how to add it?

Answer (score 0):

The required module isn't nested module because isn't in the current module directory. It's required module. So you should use `RequiredModules` instead of `NestedModules`. And be sure to setup `$env:PSModulePath` variable correctly before load modules.